# Route data passed to Angular component not set porperly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, logic

I'm developing an angular app.I will demonstrate the problem using small code snippets for clarity.

**My Component**

```
export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent {
    isuserActive = false;
    ...
}
```

**Base Component**

```
 export class BaseComponent {
    ...
    constructor() {
        this.route.data.subscribe((values: Object = {}) => {
            this['isuserActive'] = values['isuserActive'];
            ...
        });
    ...
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
... data { isuserActive: true, ...
```

But finally when I check MyComponent, its isuserActive is false which is wrong.
**But it works fine (isuserActive is true) when my component is as follows** *(that I don't prefer)*.

**My Component**

```
export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent {
    isuserActive; // no initial value (I don't prefer this way)
}
```

So how can I solve this.

Comment: add the `this.route.data.subscribe` in the ngOnInit method